# What is the purpose of using `call` here?

Tags: bash, cmd.exe

in a cmd batch file, I found the following line

```
call sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS -d main_dev -i create.sql
```

What is the purpose of using `call` here?

I am reading https://ss64.com/nt/call.html, but can't figure out which case in the link applies here.

Can we just simply run the command without `call`, i.e.

```
sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS -d main_dev -i create.sql
```

I am used to Bash. Is there some similar command in Bash or Linux to `call` in cmd?

Thanks.

Comment: Because it creates a new context for execution of the script/executable, independent of the batch files context and environment.

Comment: Thanks. I am used to Bash. Is there some similar command in Bash or Linux to `call` in cmd?

Comment: If you invoke a batch file from another, then using `call` means that it will return afterwards and continue with the original batch file. If you omit `call`, then you will chain to the file and not return.

Comment: There is no need for an equivalent in `bash`: a called script always returns. If you want to chain without returning, use `exec`.

Comment: Well, bash has an opposite equivalant (if that makes sense). In bash, the `source script.sh` or `. script.sh` will cause a script file to be executed within the same context as the script in which it occurs, whereas by default a script launched from within a script will execute with its own stdin/out/err, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to examine the batch file in which the `call` statement is found. Normally, a batch `call` statement means that there is more that needs to be done by the calling batch file, so the called batch file needs to return control to the calling batch file. If you were to make the change you inquire about, `sqlcmd` would *not* return control to the calling batch file, and anything after it would not run.

Comment: Thanks. I am used to Bash. Is there some similar command in Bash or Linux to `call` in cmd?

Comment: No, the default behavior in bash is to return to the "parent" script.